# MySQL return extra records when using a long type number to filter varchar type

Tags: mysql, precision, varchar, bigint

A simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_type_test` (  
  `uid` varchar(31) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and some records:

```
'6011656821812318924', 'a'
'6011656821812318925', 'b'
'6011656821812318926', 'c'
```

when I execute the following SQL, 3 records will return

```
select * from tbl_type_test where uid = 6011656821812318924;
```

and this will return 3 records, too. Weird.

```
select * from tbl_type_test where uid = 6011656821812318900;
```

if I change the number to string type, as expected, only 1 record will return:

```
select * from tbl_type_test where uid = '6011656821812318924';
```

I think the number type and length in the query is the reason, but I don't known the exact.

Any comment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the last one is the only correct since you compare a string with a VARCHAR field

Comment: Likely some precision loss occurring when one of your non-matching data types needs to be cast to be able to compare it to the other. Plus, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/number-literals.html says, _“Two numbers that look similar may be treated differently. For example, 2.34 is an exact-value (fixed-point) number, whereas 2.34E0 is an approximate-value (floating-point) number.”_ - so I could easily see stuff like that playing into this as well.

Comment: [...] There is simply no reason to use a number here instead of a string - otherwise the uid column could have been made a number type to begin with, but I am pretty sure it was deliberately made VARCHAR. So comparing against anything else than text would be rather nonsense to begin with.

Comment: emmmm~ what I mean is, the uid column should be the BIGINT type at first time, but in this situation, when compare a number to the varchar field, 3 records will return, what happend in MySQL?

Comment: `select '6011656821812318924' + 0` (its `6011656821812319000`) and you will see the loss of precision that's cause by the numerical conversion that your where clause requires when used with a numeric literal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does mysql 'select where clause' query wrongly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40014087/90527)

Answer (score 1):

*In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.* - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

for example

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$

create procedure p (inval float, inval2 float, inval3 float)
select inval,inval2,inval3;

call p(6011656821812318924,6011656821812318925,6011656821812318926);

+------------+------------+------------+
| inval      | inval2     | inval3     |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 6.01166e18 | 6.01166e18 | 6.01166e18 |
+------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL by default treats 1 and '1' the same however you can change that by setting the MySQL behavior to Strict mode.

set @@GLOBAL.sql_mode  = "STRICT_ALL_TABLES";
set @@SESSION.sql_mode = "STRICT_ALL_TABLES";

or you can set these variables in your my.cnf file to be permanent in sql_mode = ''. This way MySQL will throw an error if an incorrect type is used. Read 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-invalid-data.html

Regards