# What is causing it, when the value is greater than a certain number of digits, the result will be different?

Tags: mysql

I'm very sorry, before trying all the cases, I hurriedly sent an email and said sorry to everyone! Following your answer, I tried and overturned the previous idea. As the number of digits changes, I am very confused. I haven't tested how many digits are normal, but I believe this example should explain it. When the string type is compared with the number type, when the number of digits is greater than a certain value, only the same result as the number of digits to be queried is returned, but there are two cases. Are the other numbers the same? I did not try one by one. Want to understand what caused it, implicit type conversion or what?

```
  CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `simid` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `simid`)
    VALUES
    (1, 'ccc', '6441760021201308940'),
    (3, 'bb', '6441760021201308941'),
    (4, 'bb', '6441760021201308942');
    
    select * from user where simuid = 6441760021201308940;
    result：
    1 ccc 6441760021201308940
    3 bb 6441760021201308941
    4 bb 6441760021201308942
    
    but ：select * from user where simuid = '6441760021201308940';
    result：
    1 ccc 6441760021201308940

    mysql> select * from user;
    +------+------+------------------------+
    | id   | name | simid                  |
    +------+------+------------------------+
    |    5 | ccc  | 6441760021201307159    |
    |    6 | ccc  | 6441760021201307160    |
    |    7 | ccc  | 6441760021201307001    |
    |    8 | ccc  | 6441760021201307000    |
    |    9 | qqq  | 6441760021201308159    |
    |   10 | sss  | 6441760021201308160    |
    |   12 | jjj  | 641760021201308162     |
    |   13 | sss  | 6441760021201308161    |
    |   14 | jjj  | 6417600212013081620    |
    |   15 | sss  | 64417600212013081610   |
    |   21 | zzz  | 6441760021201308970    |
    |   51 | ccc  | 6441760021201308940    |
    |   52 | ddd  | 6441760021201308945    |
    |   53 | bb   | 6441760021201308941    |
    |   54 | bb   | 6441760021201308942    |
    |   55 | eee  | 6441760021201308946    |
    |  100 | sss  | 6441760021201308161000 |
    |  101 | jjj  | 641760021201308162000  |
    |  200 | sss  | 6441760021201308168000 |
    |  201 | jjj  | 6441760021201308169000 |
    | 1000 | aaa  | 64410                  |
    | 1001 | bbb  | 64411                  |
    +------+------+------------------------+
    22 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    select * from user where simid = 6441760021201307159;
        +----+------+---------------------+
        | id | name | simid               |
        +----+------+---------------------+
        |  5 | ccc  | 6441760021201307159 |
        |  6 | ccc  | 6441760021201307160 |
        |  9 | qqq  | 6441760021201308159 |
        | 10 | sss  | 6441760021201308160 |
        +----+------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from user where simid = 6441760021201308160000;
+-----+------+------------------------+
| id  | name | simid                  |
+-----+------+------------------------+
| 100 | sss  | 6441760021201308161000 |
| 200 | sss  | 6441760021201308168000 |
| 201 | jjj  | 6441760021201308169000 |
+-----+------+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
mysql> select * from user where simid = 6441760021201308160;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name | simid               |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  5 | ccc  | 6441760021201307159 |
|  6 | ccc  | 6441760021201307160 |
|  9 | qqq  | 6441760021201308159 |
| 10 | sss  | 6441760021201308160 |
+----+------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from user where simid = 6441760021201308161;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name | simid               |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 13 | sss  | 6441760021201308161 |
| 21 | zzz  | 6441760021201308970 |
| 51 | ccc  | 6441760021201308940 |
| 52 | ddd  | 6441760021201308945 |
| 53 | bb   | 6441760021201308941 |
| 54 | bb   | 6441760021201308942 |
| 55 | eee  | 6441760021201308946 |
+----+------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You posted sample data and queries without explaining what the problem is. What results do you expect? What is not working? I only see that you are trying to match a VARCHAR column with a number. Why?

Comment: @forpas Thank you for your reminder, let me edit it again

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1fe7b87969eb4b43702f7a1923786031 Also `simid` is not the same as `simuid`.

Comment: @forpas I am very sorry, but this happens because I thought it was related to the character set, and the character set was modified for the field, but the field name was changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Why does mysql 'select where clause' query wrongly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40014087/90527)", "[MySQL return extra records when using a long type number to filter varchar type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49323126/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `VARCHAR` and `INTEGER` values you are trying to compare are converted to `FLOAT` numbers by MySQL, as defined in [12.3 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

They even have an example which shows your problem:

> To illustrate, only the first of the following comparisons compares equal values, but both comparisons return true (1):
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT '9223372036854775807' = 9223372036854775807;
>        -> 1
> mysql> SELECT '9223372036854775807' = 9223372036854775806;
>        -> 1
> ```

The solution is simple: Do not compare `VARCHAR` and `INTEGER` values. Or you can use the [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function as mentioned in the documentation above.