# why "349664763740905440" =349664763740905470 is true?

Tags: mysql

The problem is different value compare is true. I don't understand.

mysql version : 5.7

my test demo:

```
SELECT "349664763740905430" =349664763740905470; -- 0
SELECT "349664763740905440" =349664763740905470; -- 1
SELECT "349664763740905500" =349664763740905470; -- 1
SELECT "349664763740905510" =349664763740905470; -- 0
```

does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Why does mysql 'select where clause' query wrongly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40014087/90527)", "[MySQL return extra records when using a long type number to filter varchar type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49323126/90527)," "[What is causing it, when the value is greater than a certain number of digits, the result will be different?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64400898/90527)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Functions and Operators  /  Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

> The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations:
>
> ...
>
> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

So use explicit datatype convertion for to set needed (numeric) comparing context. For example

```sql
SELECT CAST('349664763740905500' AS UNSIGNED) =349664763740905470;
```